# How the handler instance runs a runnable even the app is killed in android?

Tags: android, android-handler

In my app, I have a handler in the MainActivity. In this handler, I get the timestamp value from the local database, change its value to current timestamp and update the local database. This event happens for every 2 minutes.

My problem is the local database should not be updated when my app is killed. But, the code in the handler runs even my app is killed and updated the timestamp value in the local database. So, when I open the app again it doesnot give me the last timestamp value that is stored in the database before my app is killed.

How to stop the handler when I kill my app? It is worth if explain me how the handler works exactly.

Source code:

```
    addEventHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                mockSpeedEventHandler.postDelayed(this, realTimeEventFrequency * 60 * 1000);
        }
    }, 60000);
```

Comment: Do you have this `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` in `onStop()` or any where else in activity?

Comment: I have stopped the addEventHandler in onDestroy() by calling the             addEventHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using 2 handlers, but if assume that the code that runs is triggered by the 2nd one. The solution should be to stop both addEventHandler and mockSpeedEventHandler.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you please explain why Android did not stop the handler when the app is killed?

Comment: the handler execution as is being scheduled is not released and the references used inside the handler thread are not released either, so you need to be careful with it, you can create a memory leak in this way

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. One final question. I can't understand this "Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread’s message queue." In this statement, the "thread" refers to the "runnable" parameter we are given to the handler in postDelayed() method or it refers to the main thread(UI) thread in which we created that Handler instance?

Comment: it's related to the handler thread creation, so in this case I believe your code is from the UI thread.